# Is it possible to do a bulk Retrieve of ResultItem in Exact Target?

Tags: marketing-cloud

I am trying retrieve the result of a triggered send in Exact Target , salesforce marketing cloud. I am able to successfully retrieve the status of a single request by passing the requestId in my soap request body, However, wanted to know if we can pass a list of such requestIds and make this operation a bulk operation?

Below is the sample request body I'm using for single request.

ResultItem
            RequestType
            StatusCode
            StatusMessage
            ErrorCode
            RequestObjectType
            
               RequestID
               equals
               9bf5f8e6-4b07-4f38-adf6-c7bda286f9ba

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using the equals operator use IN, then pass in all the values you need in the values array.